# SignalR Redis make IIS crash

Tags: performance, redis, signalr

I'm using SignalR version 1.1, ServiceStack.Redis -Version 4.0.62 and Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis -Version 1.1.4 
All is running perfectly in my development environment, then I moved "myapp" to our next environment with about 200 client, the error has occurred and IIS has crashed.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/952r2.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obTQB.png)

Can I test my signalr + redis performance with 1 computer?

Comment: I'm only seeing the stack trace in those screen shots, what exception are you getting?  Have you looked at the event log on the machine in question?  How did you load test the application on your local machine?

Comment: Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: Message: The connection has been closed (ClientClosed); no new messages can be delivered; the last command was sent 2657ms ago

Comment: I'm using SignalR with hub connection. What should i do to load test the application on my local machine ?